# Extract part of an URL behind a login page with Paw

Tags: paw-app

I'm a newbie but I think Paw can do what i need :

I need to extract a session id behind a login page. 
I go to https://admin.booking.com, filling the form (login and pass) and the landing page behind includes a session id :
https://admin.booking.com/pc/index.html?**ses=xxxxyyyyyzzzzz11112222233333**

I'd like to :

1) Push credentials with Paw as part of my request,

2) get the above item (ses) item as a response so i can use the php script extension provided by Paw and then call this script "on demand".

Is this possible ? If so, what should i do ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE*:** we've added a documentation article to describe the process a little more: [Login via a web form in Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/advanced/login-web-form). We've detailed the process to deal with CSRF tokens too.

---

Paw isn't quite yet ready for handling web/HTML forms. Though, there's one way to do it the right way: if you inspect the form with the Chrome dev tools you'll find the `name` of the input from the DOM/HTML:

[image: Find HTML input to use in a Paw form]

In your case, you have the inputs: `loginname`, `password`, `lang`.
Also, find the `<form…>` tag to see what's the `action` attribute. If there's no `action` attribute (like in your example), it means the target URL for your form is the current page's URL (`https://admin.booking.com/` in your case). Also, make sure the `method="POST"` is also there in the `<form…>` tag, otherwise this method won't work.

Then jump into Paw and set:

- URL (in your case `https://admin.booking.com/`)
- method to POST
- go to the Body tab and use "Form URL-Encoded + fill up the fields from your form

[image: Simulate an HTML form in Paw]

If all works, you'll see Paw show a redirection request, and if you go to the right-hand side panel under "Response" > "Headers", you should see a `Location` header with a value similar to the URL you initially mentioned (`https://admin.booking.com/pc/index.html?ses=xxxxyyyyyzzzzz11112222233333`). Hurray! You got your value into Paw!

Now that you have that, you can create in a new request (click on the + button at the bottom of the left-hand side list). And wherever you want to use this session token/ID, you can insert a dynamic value to retrieve that URL value. You have more infos [here, in our docs](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/advanced/reuse-values-from-previous-responses), but I'll describe the steps here:

On whichever field you want to insert the token, right-click and pick Responses > Response Header.

[image: Insert a response header Dynamic Value in Paw]

Make sure you pick the first request in the "Request" dropdown menu, and enter `Location` in the "Header" field:

[image: Use a header dynamic value for a redirection-based login in Paw]

You should see the value of the `Location` header of the previous response appear here.

Now what you want to do is to extract only the part you want (i.e. the value of the `ses` param in your case). For that you'll need that extension for Paw, so please install it now: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/RegExMatch

Copy the dynamic value you have just inserted (the blue token), and right-click on that field to insert a new dynamic value, and pick Extensions > RegExp match:

[image: Pick a RegExp match dynamic value in Paw to extract a field from a previous response]

In the Input field, paste the previous dynamic value you copied. And use the RegExp field to write a regular expression that will successfully extract the part of the URL you want (this should work in your case `ses=(.*)`).

[image: Extract a field from the header of a previous response in Paw]

Now that you're set up. You should be able to use this little new blue token wherever you like and automagically extract the value from the previous form. And whenever you send again the initial request, and get a new token, everything else will also update! :)

*It was a little long guide, but I hope this will help you and hopefully others too.*

Comment: Hello Micha, Thank you SO much for this. This is great guide and it should definitely do the job. I understood the workflow perfectly and it does make a lot of sense. However, the "password" field does not accept to be populated from Paw as he has the "autocomplete=off" enabled when i'm inspecting the field. The form URL is the below : [link](https://admin.booking.com/partner/login.html)....Do you have any idea to bypass this ? Thank you for your help. Best, David

Comment: Hey David, I've updated my answer above with the doc article we've added today to give some steps to other users having the same problem. The issue you're facing is because the form expects a CSRF token to be passed, and it seems like the Booking.com form is injecting this token via JavaScript at submit time, which won't be possible to reproduce in Paw. Have a look to the doc article, it might give you some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: You can send us an email at support@luckymarmot.com we can help you further…